# Timing problem with ReplaceRepeated

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, replacement

I have the following data:

```
data = 
 {{{1931, 1, 1}, 7.78}, {{1931, 1, 2}, 5.}, {{1931, 1, 3}, "x"}, 
  {{1931, 1, 4}, "x"}, {{1931, 1, 16}, 5.`}, {{1931, 1, 17}, 3.89`}, 
  {{1931, 1, 18}, "x"}, {{1931, 1, 20}, 2.22`}};
```

I want to replace the "x"-values with the last preceding number:

```
data //. {a___, b : {_, c_}, {d_, "x"}, e___} :> {a, b, {d, c}, e}
```

gives the expected result:

> ```
> {{{1931, 1, 1}, 7.78}, {{1931, 1, 2}, 5.}, {{1931, 1, 3}, 5.}, 
>  {{1931,1, 4}, 5.}, {{1931, 1, 16}, 5.}, {{1931, 1, 17}, 3.89}, 
>  {{1931, 1, 18}, 3.89}, {{1931, 1, 20}, 2.22}}
> ```

but becomes very slow as elements grow: $4.6$ seconds with $10000$ elements and seemingly forever with $25000$. My lists are long ($25000+$ elements) but have very few ($50$ - $100$) "x"-values.

I have no idea how a fast functional solution could look like.

Comment: `g[v : {s_List, n_?NumericQ}] := (temp = n; v);
g[v : {s_List, "x"}] := {s, temp};
g /@ data`

Comment: Thanks @ belisarius - your solution is right, short and fast. Would you post it as an answer ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `data` looks like an `EventSeries` to me. Therefore let's treat it like one.

```
es = EventSeries[data /. "x" -> Missing[], 
  MissingDataMethod -> {"Interpolation", InterpolationOrder -> 0}]

es["Path"]
```

> ```
> {{978220800, 7.78}, {978307200, 5.}, {978393600, 5.}, {978480000, 5.}, {979516800, 5.}, 
>  {979603200, 3.89}, {979689600, 3.89}, {979862400, 2.22}}
> ```

Or

```
es["DatePath"] // Normal
```

> ```
> {{{1931, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, 7.78}, {{1931, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0.}, 5.}, 
>  {{1931, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0.}, 5.}, {{1931, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0.}, 5.}, 
>  {{1931, 1, 16, 0, 0, 0.}, 5.}, {{1931, 1, 17, 0, 0, 0.}, 3.89}, 
>  {{1931, 1, 18, 0, 0, 0.}, 3.89}, {{1931, 1, 20, 0, 0, 0.}, 2.22}}
> ```

---

`AbsoluteTiming`s for a list with 15492 entries, 37 % containing `"x"`:

- `ReplaceRepeated`: 7326.01
- `Map` `data`: 0.0268449
- `Map` `data[[All, 2]]`: 0.0175813
- `Scan`: 0.0581277
- `FoldList`: 0.123955
- `EventSeries`: 0.727509

Creating the `EventSeries` object costs some extra time, but it is potentially advantageous for the subsequent processing.

Comment: Yes indeed, dates with (missing) values. A very interesting solution with some options to play with. Thank you :)

Answer (score 10):

Without patterns:

```
g[v : {s_List, n_?NumericQ}] := (temp = n; v); 
g[v : {s_List, "x"}] := {s, temp}; 

g /@ data
```

> {{{1931, 1, 1}, 7.78}, {{1931, 1, 2}, 5.}, {{1931, 1, 3}, 5.}, {{1931, 1, 4}, 5.}, {{1931, 1, 16}, 5.}, {{1931, 1, 17}, 3.89}, {{1931, 1, 18}, 3.89}, {{1931, 1, 20}, 2.22}}

Or even faster:

```
data[[All, 2]] = Block[{temp, g},
   g[n_?NumericQ] := temp = n;
   g["x"] := temp; g /@ data[[All, 2]]];
```

Comment: It's even faster, if you only `Map` over the second column: `data[[All, 2]] = Block[{temp, g},
   g[n_?NumericQ] := temp = n;
   g["x"] := temp; g /@ data[[All, 2]]];`

Comment: @Karsten7. Thanks! I made that yesterday but haven't have the time to check the performance. Feel free to edit the answer!

Comment: +1. Great Answer, Is there any reason you choose `Block` not `Module`?

Comment: @Algohi In general using `Block` is faster, that's the only reason.

Answer (score 6):

This should do what you want:

```
Rest @ FoldList[
  Replace[{##}, {{{_, c_}, {d_, "x"}} :> {d, c}, {_, arg_} :> arg}]&,
  {}, 
  data
]
```

while being functional and hopefully fast enough.

Comment: Thanks, much to learn for me from your answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Using `Position` and `Scan` a fast solution is possible.

**Proof of concept**

First a short synthetic data set for proof of concept.

```
dataN = {{1931, RandomInteger[{1, 12}], RandomInteger[{1, 30}]}, 
          RandomReal[{1., 10.}]} & /@ Range[2];

dataX = {{1931, RandomInteger[{1, 12}], RandomInteger[{1, 30}]}, 
         "x"} & /@ Range[2];

data = Riffle[dataN, dataX]

{{{1931, 12, 13}, 3.89908}, {{1931, 3, 28}, "x"}, 
{{1931, 8, 6}, 2.41899}, {{1931, 7, 2}, "x"}}
```

Very simply we get the position of elements that contain the string "x" and then replace them, using `Scan`, with the numerical value preceding it in the same position.

Since we start at the beginning repeated elements with "x" will have the same preceding value.

```
Scan[
 (data[[Sequence @@ #]] = data[[#[[1]] - 1, #[[2]]]]) &,
 Position[data, "x"]
 ]
```

produces

```
{{{1931, 5, 1}, 4.47596}, {{1931, 1, 15}, 4.47596},
 {{1931, 5, 13}, 8.81877}, {{1931, 5, 6}, 8.81877}}
```

**Timing**

Now we make a large (25000) length dataset.

```
dataN = {{1931, RandomInteger[{1, 12}], RandomInteger[{1, 30}]}, 
     RandomReal[{1., 10.}]} & /@ Range[12500];

dataX = {{1931, RandomInteger[{1, 12}], RandomInteger[{1, 30}]}, 
     "x"} & /@ Range[12500];

data = Riffle[dataN, dataX];
```

Run and time the `Scan` and check the results.

```
Scan[
  (data[[Sequence @@ #]] = data[[#[[1]] - 1, #[[2]]]]) &,
  Position[data, "x"]
  ] // Timing

{0.171601, Null}
```

With this test data every other component had an "x". Check the first four:

```
data[[1 ;; 4]]

{{{1931, 8, 27}, 9.75179}, {{1931, 2, 17}, 9.75179},
 {{1931, 8, 5}, 1.3279}, {{1931, 6, 8}, 1.3279}}
```

Leonid's approach took 0.218 seconds.

Belisarius's approach was the fastest: 0.0468 seconds.

Comment: You don't need the `Scan[ ]` part. Like this`(data[[#, 2]] = data[[# - 1, 2]]) & /@ (Position[data, "x"][[All, 1]])`

Comment: @belisariusisforth `Scan` works slightly faster on my system than `Map`. My perception is that `Scan` should be used when you are only producing side effects. Reformulating `(data[[Sequence @@ #]] = data[[#[[1]] - 1, #[[2]]]]) &, Position[data, "x"]` to `(data[[#, 2]] = data[[# - 1, 2]]) &, Position[data, "x"][[All, 1]]]` provides a speed up.

Comment: Seems you're right :)